# invalid associated content type in the pagelayout SP 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I have developed custom web-page-layouts with the associated welcome page and deployed.
It shows me **Invalid Associated Content Type** instead of **Content Type Title**.
What's wrong here?
[image]